# Is it possible to use mapstruct together with jpastreamer?

Tags: spring, maven, mapstruct, annotation-processing

i'm writing a spring-boot project in which i'm using mapstruct. Code that mapstruct generates is located in `target/generated-sources/annotations`.

I would like to use also jpastreamer library. I used `build-helper-maven-plugin` to generate metamodel.

The problem i'm facing is that this library also generates `metamodel` into the same directory, so only the code generated by mapstruct is available.

Here is my code:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>16</release>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The metamodels for JPAStreamers are not generating when using in the same projects as that with MapStruct. When tried on a separate project. That worked fine. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which library jpastream is. However, if it is an annotation processor then you should include that as part of the `maven-compiler-plugin` `annotationProcessorPaths`. That way all the annotation processors will be invoked in the same time and the code will be appropriately generated.

The fact that you only see the code generated by MapStruct in the `target/generated-sources/annotations` folder is due to the fact that the `maven-compiler-plugin` deletes everything from that folder before running the annotation processors.

If that jpastream library is not an annotation processor but something else, then you should generate its classes in another locaton not `target/generated-sources/annotations`, but rather `target/generated-sources/jpastream`

Comment: Thank you Filip for your help :) 
Sorry, I made a mistake in the library name - it is actually JPAstremer. My fault. It is available here: https://jpastreamer.org/

I tried to modify the output folder of the 'generate-sources' phase, but I don't see any option among configuration options for that phase. 

I tried to use 'generatedSourcesDirectory', but I think it applies changes to both of the source processors.

Answer (score 0):

You need specify `jpastreamer`'s annotation processor side by side with `mapstruct`'s

Here's a sample `pom.xml` excerpt with `JPAStreamer`, `mapstruct` and `lombok`. I believe this will apply

```xml
     <!-- .... -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jpastreamer-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${jpastreamer.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     <!-- .... -->
```